# Selenium/Katalon can not get webelement's text when running in jenkins or headless

Tags: selenium, jenkins, katalon-studio

I have a button's text `<span _ngcontent-c4="" class="btn__text">FOO</span>`
When running Katalon (6.3.3) test localy everything is ok, but when running in jenkins the text FOO is loaded as empty string.
To capture the FOO text I'm using:

```
WebUI.verifyElementText(findTestObject('TC01/header/button_FOO'), "FOO")
```

Even when converting the element to `org.openqa.selenium.WebElement` and use `element.getText()`, local run get the text FOO just fine and in jenkins:

```
ERROR c.k.k.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain  - ? Actual text '' and expected text 'FOO' of test object 'Object Repository/TC01/header/button_FOO' are NOT matched.
```

Testing page title same way works fine even in jenkins run.

In jenkins image is Google Chrome 79.0.3945.88 and ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36

In local machine is Chrome 79.0.3945.88 and ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36

The jenkins image is linux and I'm on Win 10.

After I added argument --headless, problem started to occure on local run as well.

Comment: better to share more code with your question, did you try adding a waitForElementVisible before you click that object?,

Comment: @lahimadhe the webelement is located ok, I can get it's attributes. But can not get it's text.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved** with adding argument `--window-size=1920x1080`.
Now works fine even in jenkins.